# Animating a Double Collection Value at Runtime

Tags: silverlight, xaml, animation, shapes, visualstatemanager

Say I have a shape. I've given it a `Stroke` and `StrokeThickness` and a `StrokeDashArray` to get the desired dashed outline. Then I animate the `StrokeDashOffset` via `VisualStateManager` to get the "Marching Ants" style animation to it. Everything works great...

Except I want the default of the shape to NOT have a `StrokeDashArray` and instead want to set that based on a `VisualState` in the `VisualStateManager` except unfortunately as we know I can only do a `DoubleAnimation` on a Property, and not a Double Collection Value like what `StrokeDashArray` is...

My question is, is there a clever way I could animate that value during runtime so the shape in an UnSelected State has a solid `Stroke` but via the 'VisualStateManager' (maybe) still supply the `StrokeDashOffset` on the Selected State to the same shape? Or am I better off having two separate shapes and toggling the visibility between them so that each have their own default values?

If it would help visualize with a picture or something let me know and I'll add more to the question.

Comment: Adding code and other visuals will always help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to animate a double property and create a new DoubleCollection that is bound to the StrokeDashArray.

Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Name="UI">
<Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="StrokeDashArrayAnimation">
                <Storyboard BeginTime="0">
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:5"
                                     From="0"
                                     Storyboard.TargetName="UI"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeValue"
                                     To="10" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Ellipse x:Name="lo"
             Stroke="Red"
             StrokeDashArray="{Binding StrokeArray}"
             StrokeThickness="5" />
    <Button Width="150"
            Height="49"
            Margin="29,65,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Click="Button_Click_1"
            Content="Start" />
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {


    public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public double StrokeValue
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(StrokeValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StrokeValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeValue", typeof(double), typeof(MainPage),
            new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnStrokeValueChanged));

        private static void OnStrokeValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var page = d as MainPage;
            if (page != null) page.StrokeArray = new DoubleCollection { (double)e.NewValue, 1 };
        }

        public DoubleCollection StrokeArray
        {
            get { return (DoubleCollection)GetValue(StrokeArrayProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StrokeArrayProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeArrayProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeArray", typeof(DoubleCollection), typeof(MainPage)
            , new PropertyMetadata(new DoubleCollection { 0, 1 }));


        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "StrokeDashArrayAnimation", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well that's looking like a clever way, I'll have to try this out a little later and see how it does, and I think it gave me an idea for another route either way. Sorry for the delayed response, been away for a bit, cheers.